# script in cronjob doesn't work with: "Could not open input file"

Tags: files, scripting, cron, php

This is my code in `scriptrun` (name of my shell script):

```
php -f a1.php; php -f b2.php; sh -e c3.txt
```

This is my cronjob command: `/home/telia/www/robot/scriptrun`, created as root

When I run script I get error message

```
Could not open input file: a1.php      
Could not open input file: b2.php
```

scriptrun file is already have +x and I already tried

```
/usr/bin/php -f a1.php; /usr/bin/php b2.php ;sh -e c3.txt
```

I tried giving 777 chmod to php files however doesn't change anything.

script runs perfectly if I try manually it is just not work with cronjob.

Comment: Enter the full path to the a1.php, b2.php and c3.txt files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was [answered in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), the problem appears to be that your a1.php and b2.php scripts are not in your $HOME directory, which is where cron jobs will execute. Either add a `cd /to/that/path` command to your `scriptrun` script, or change the `php` commands to use the full path to those scripts.